# Pass existing matplotlib axis object to wxmplot / wxpython

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, axis

Lets assume i have a class which handels my data processing and this class contains a function that delivers my a standardize plot with a function that retunrs an matplotlib axis object.... now someone wants a GUI for this...

```
def get_plot(self, ax=None,.... *lkwargs)
       # This function does some stuff and returns "ax": a matplotlib axis object
    return ax
```

now want i want to do is to use the ax object with wxmplot. Ideally i want to pass the existing ax object with all its handels / content to wxmplot. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is "No".  Wxmplot creates matplotlib `figure` and `axes` objects, but none of the main interface routines accept matplotlib objects.

OTOH, one can access the matplotlib axis *after* the wxmplot plotting objects are created.  That is, it is possible to "do some stuff" (depending on the details) with the underlying `axes`.